# Fatal Error While trying to open Joomla Redirect Component

Tags: php, joomla3.0

When I try to open my Joomla's Redirect component I see this line: **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 15787096 bytes) in /home/creativicamag/public_html/libraries/phputf8/mbstring/core.php on line 121**

Please help me out!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem that you redirect table contain a high number of values that reach your php memory limit.
You have to add a php.ini file in your root directory with:

> memory_limit = 512M

You could also try to add in your .htaccess file:

> php_value memory_limit 512M

Another way is to access your redirects table and clean it via phpmyadmin.

Comment: WOW! It works! I opened the .htaccess file and added the line you said! Thanks!